# I installed an SSL certificate in nginx but writing the url in the browser tells me: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Node js application that listens to port 3000. I installed nginx and configured it so that it redirects the data from port 80 to 3000 using the following line:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

I also have an assigned domain name: okium.fun. Finally I bought an SSL certificate and configured the file `/etc/nginx/sites-aviable/default` to try to make it work. My default file looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  listen 443 ssl;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name  okium.fun;

  ssl_certificate /root/okium.fun.chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /root/okium.fun.key;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

When writing http://okium.fun or http://www.okium.fun in the browser the application is displayed correctly but when typing https://okium.fun or https://www.okium.fun I get the following message "The okium.fun page has rejected the connection. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

Any ideas of what may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions:

1) Remove iptables redirect, you would probably want nginx to deal with redirects, not iptables.

`-D` flag will undo iptables rule:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

2) Inspect your iptables configuration, especially `Chain INPUT` section, it should allow incoming connections to 443 port.

Here is how you can enable it: `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT`

3) Make sure nginx is up and running `systemctl status nginx`. It looks like your connections to port 80 was previously redirected by iptables directly to your node.js application.

4) Make sure nginx reads your configuration.
Check out nginx config file (`less /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`), most likely it will have lines like this:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

If this is the case, folder `sites-aviable` is not read by default and you will need to create symlink to your custom config file:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-aviable/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

5) Update your `/etc/nginx/sites-aviable/default` config to include proxy_pass rule:

```
server {
    server_name okium.fun;

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    # your ssl configuration here
    # ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

6) Test your nginx configuration: `sudo nginx -t`.
If everything is ok you will see message like this:

```
the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
```

7) Reload nginx `sudo nginx -s reload` and check out if you can connect via https.

8) If you still getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, revisit you iptables configuration `sudo iptables -nL` and make sure nginx is listening 443 port `sudo lsof -i`.

Comment: I have reached step 6 but at the time of writing `sudo nginx -t` it returns me: `nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed` . I went to the route `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` and the `default` file exists but is empty...

Comment: Looks like an issue with a symlink. Double check that name for config file in _sites-available_ directory is indeed _default_: `cd /etc/nginx/sites-available; ls -la;` and try to re-create a symlink. 

Also you can create configuration file directly in _/etc/nginx/sites-enabled_ directory without even using a symlink.

Comment: Okay, I have done all the steps and now I get the following error: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED. When I write the command `sudo iptables -nL` one of the lines it returns to me looks like this: `ACCEPT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0   0.0.0.0/0   tcp dpt:443`

Comment: I assume that nginx is up and running and you can connect via http to nodejs app, then this might be caused by incomplete configuration file (`sites-available/default`), e.g. missing `ssl on;` statement or something like this. Please, verify your configuration file, [here is good example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins).

Comment: Also double check if nginx listens https `sudo lsof -i` and check out nginx logs (`less /var/log/nginx/error.log` and `less /var/log/nginx/access.log`)

Comment: Egor, thank you for taking the time to respond. I was trying many things until I finally deleted the server and created a new one but now redirected from nginx and not from iptables. Everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As you know https is the port 443 but you set listen 433 ssl;..

433 is not 443 .. just a typo

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just corrected it but I get the same error

Comment: [root@ns397628 ~]# telnet okium.fun 443
Trying 134.209.14.125...
telnet: connect to address 134.209.14.125: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
[root@ns397628 ~]#

Comment: Please restart the nginx .. or otherwise is a firewall issue

Comment: Sorry more like is not the nginx issue because you forward the destination port 80 to your application so you have to do it for the 443 also or do a nginx proxy pass. Can your node.js application which runs on 3000 serve SSL if not than is nginx fastcgi pass:   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo writing the port number in default file.

I think the port should be mentioned as `443` instead of `433` in the configuration of ssl cert

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just corrected it but I get the same error...

Comment: after that you need to restart your nginx machine by "sudo service nginx restart"